# A 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to add a 404 error page to my website, however, I'm getting this error when I try to access it.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /asd.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My .htaccess page contains only the following line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404-page.php;
```

And the following 404-page.php file is in the same directory as the .htaccess file, so I'm unsure as to why this is happening.

```
<?php
    require "header.php";
?>

    <main>
        <h2>404 - Page not found</h2>
        <p>The page you are looking for was not found, if this is an error please contact administration.</p>
    </main>

<?php
    require "footer.php";
    ?>
```

I've tried just using a html page for the 404, as well as uploading the page to a host, but neither has worked.

The directory for the host goes:

```
/
 public_html
   404-page.php
   .htaccess
```

Comment: Have you tried checking whether `htaccess` is parsed after all, for example through putting an invalid string in there?

Comment: @NicoHaase I just tried putting an invalid path and in return <action> part of the command e.g. path/404-page.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error, turns out it's because I had an ';' at the end of the line which is the reason it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your path may not be the absolute path. Try setting an absolute path i.e

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/404/404-page.php
```

try your http:// path instead of /path/to/404/404-page.php 
This will depend on your configuration. Please see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html

Comment: Didn't work, I've not configured anything so it is whatever the default is.

Comment: The 404 page is in the root directory with the .htaccess file.

Comment: HI, could you try with the literal browser path? please see  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html

Answer (score 0):

the path may not be the absolute path to your htdocs folder root but instead the root of your filesystem.
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domainname.com/404-page.php;

Answer (score 0):

Go to httpd.conf file in Apache Folder and add an absolute path like this

`ErrorDocument 404 /nameofyourproject/index.html`